# Outdated Jar in Classpath Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, classpath, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to run some code in Databricks with a Jar attached. The error I'm getting is associated with an outdated Jar in the class path. I've uploaded the latest Jar but apparently the outdated version is still somewhere in the class path. Is there a way to access, view, or edit the class path in Databricks?

Would deleting that cluster and building a new cluster fix the problem?

Sorry for the hypothetical, I'm 0% familiar with class paths. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Scala notebook, use this code:

```
val jarfiles = dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/FileStore/jars")

.map(_.path)

.filter(_.indexOf("your pattern") > -1)

jarfiles.foreach(dbutils.fs.rm(_))
```

Replace "your pattern" with a string in the name of your jar (but isn't common enough to delete other jars).

Restart cluster, boom